# How to import or inject dependencies with `Depends()` in an interactive shell?

Tags: python, ipython, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI and finding some features related with interactive shell.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find it and just tried to run below code on ipython.

```py
# src/repositories/__init__.py

class A:
    def greet(self) -> str:
        print('hello')
        return 'hello'


class B:
    def __call__(self, a: A = Depends()):
        return a.greet()
```

```py
>>> from src.repositories import B
>>> b = B()
>>> b()

AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'greet'
```

To use a class which depends on another class in an interactive shell, should I pass the dependencies manually? Or is there any method to do it automatically with FastAPI's `Depends`?

Comment: If you run your script directly (not in a Python shell), do you get the same error?

Comment: @GinoMempin Of course yes. Wouldn't it be the same if the code is not executed within the fastapi environment whether it was run as a interactive shell or a python script?

Comment: My point is if you can reproduce it _outside_ of an interactive Python shell, then it's _not_ an issue specific/related to running the code inside a Python shell. It's an issue of the code itself. Just trying to help you debug and not focus on "*some features related with interactive shell.*"

Comment: The `Depends` decorators are only evaluated in a FastAPI context (i.e. when FastAPI does its magic around them). This has been discussed in #1105: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1105 - "if your code runs outside of FastAPI you're better using explicit objects. Dependencies are, in the end, a way to get or process data based on a request. But if your code is not related to a request (not in a FastAPI app) then there's no advantage and it would just add complexity to your code."

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't related *at all* to running it in a Python interactive shell (be it IPython, Jupyter, etc.), because you'll get the same problem if you run it is a regular Python script:

```
$ cat test.py 
from fastapi import Depends

class A:
    def greet(self) -> str:
        print('hello')
        return 'hello'

class B:
    def __call__(self, a: A = Depends()):
        return a.greet()

b = B()
b()

$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    b()
  File "/path/to/test.py", line 11, in __call__
    return a.greet()
AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'greet'
```

[As pointed out by MatsLindh in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73890754/how-to-import-or-generate-deps-injected-class-for-fastapi-in-interactive-shell#comment130472922_73890754), the issue is with *using `Depends` outside of a request-response context*:

**[QUESTION] - Using Depends() in other functions, outside the endpoint path operation!**
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1105

> **Dependencies are, in the end, a way to get or process data based on a request. But if your code is not related to a request (not in a FastAPI app) then there's no advantage and it would just add complexity to your code.**
>
> On the other side, a dependency function is in the end, just a function. So, if you pass all the arguments with the correct values instead of letting it get the default value returned by Depends() you can just use it directly as a normal function.

FastAPI is a framework for creating web applications, and because of that most of its (magic) functionalities are assuming you will use them to make APIs and the code is running in a request context (ex. as part of calling a route function).

I don't know what your code with `Depends` is supposed to achieve, but you are better off using "regular" Python and pass the dependencies "manually":

```
In [11]: from typing import Type

In [12]: class A:
    ...:     def greet(self) -> str:
    ...:         print('hello')
    ...:         return 'hello'
    ...: 

In [13]: class B:
    ...:     def __init__(self, a: Type[A]):
    ...:         self._a = a
    ...:     def __call__(self):
    ...:         return self._a.greet()
    ...: 

In [14]: b = B(A())

In [15]: b()
hello
Out[15]: 'hello'
```